# Cowplot clips labels when plotted with y >1 on multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, cowplot

First, some mock graphs:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 2:11)
```

Because my real graphs are fairly complicated, I'm going not going to provide them here, but will use other graphs that reproduce the problem. Suffice it to say that when `align` is set to `"hv"` in `plot_grid`, it creates a lot of white space between my graphs. To fix that, I set the margins in the original plots like so:

```
library(ggplot2)

plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-1, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))
plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = y, y = -x)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-1, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))
plot3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-1, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))
plot4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = y, y = -x)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-1, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))
```

Which extended the tops of the plots so they fill the white space. All fine and dandy (in this example, there may be a little overlap between the top and bottom):

```
library(cowplot)

plot5 <- plot_grid(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, 
                   align = "hv")
plot5
```

Until I tried to add labels. Because I had extended the plots, I wanted to add the labels higher than the `y = 1` limit.

```
plot5 <- plot_grid(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, 
                   align = "hv", labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                 label_x = 0.1,
                 label_y = 1.15)+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(3, 1, 1, 1), "cm"))
plot5
```

Returns this warning:

```
Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

[image]

Meaning it took off the two top labels, even though there appears to be sufficient space. So, I thought, perhaps the plot margins aren't being applied until after the labels are plotted, or perhaps clipping was causing a problem. So, I did this:

```
plot5 <- plot_grid(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, 
                   align = "hv") + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "cm")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")

plot5 + 
  draw_plot_label(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), c(0, 0.5, 0, 0.5), c(1.1, 1.1, .5, .5))
```

[image]
Which returns the same error as before, although, as you can see, there is more space availiable at the top of the plot. As a last resort, I also turned off the clipping in the original plots, but that didn't fix anything either, eg:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-1, 0, 0, 0), "cm")) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

The problem only occurs when I plot past `y = 1`. `y = 1.01` causes problems, for instance.
How do I fix this problem? It seems like a rather simple issue, unless there's a problem with `ggplot` or `cowplot`.

Comment: Not an answer - I recently had the problem of lots of white space around single plots using `plot_grid`, using library `egg` instead of `cowplot` solved the problem without having to adjust margins etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Will check it out.

Comment: I'm not clear exactly where you want the labels to be. y = 1 is by definition the top of the plot area for that plot, and anything above 1 will be outside the plot area. If you look at the code for `cowplot::plot_grid`, it calls `cowplot::ggdraw` with its default limits of `c(0, 1)` for both x and y to create its plot, and that in turn uses `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous` with those limits. Labels are plotted using those limits, so by standard ggplot rules, anything outside will be removed.

Comment: The problem I had was whitespace - too much between the plots. So I extended the plots. This fixed the whitespace in the middle of the grid, but pushed the top plots to the boundary of `y=1`. So, when I plotted the labels, they were on top of the plots. I therefore had to plot past `y=1`, which isn't possible, even if you add extra margins around the entire grid.

Answer (score 1):

By following the suggestion to use the 'egg' package, I fixed the problem: remove whitespace between graphs and have plots labelled in a sensible way.

Also, it's worth noting that egg seems faster than cowplot in drawing plots.

```
install.packages("egg")
library(egg)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 2:11)

plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))
plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = y, y = -x)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))
plot3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))
plot4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = y, y = -x)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))

figure <- egg::ggarrange(plot1, plot2, 
         plot3, plot4, 
             nrow = 2,ncol=2,
             labels=c("A", "B", "C","D"),
             label.args = list(gp=gpar(font=2), x=unit(.5,"line")))
figure
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have an answer, which fixes the matter of labels, but it doesn't solve the problem of not being able to plot past `y=1`. Instead of reducing the top margins in the original plots, I reduced the bottom margins:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 0, -1, 0), "cm"))
plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = y, y = -x)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 0, -1, 0), "cm"))
plot3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 0, -1, 0), "cm"))
plot4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = y, y = -x)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 0, -1, 0), "cm"))

plot5 <- plot_grid(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, 
                   align = "hv", labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                   label_x = 0.1,
                   label_y = 1) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 2, 1), "cm"))
plot5
```

Which lets me plot the labels in a sensible spot.
[image]

It still makes zero sense to me, though, why the labels are clipped (and it also appears to happen when y<0).